# Using java Code in linux

Tags: java, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute system commands (linux/bsd) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java)

Using java code ,how to  run rpm command in fedora.

I want to run :

" rpm -ivh progname.rpm "
throw java code

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command..");
```