# How to read all network cards with java

Tags: java, linux, networking

I want to lookup in my system (using java) for all network cards and network interfaces. So, more exactly, I want to get the whole output from `ifconfig` command (in Linux) but in Java. I know if I use `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` will return only configured network interfaces.

A rough approach I found at [this](http://sourcezone.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/java-how-to-get-the-mac-addresses-of-network-cards/) link. It is OK, but I'm interested if there are other 
possibilities on this.

Comment: you can execute system commands in java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java

Comment: @fsonmezay Yes, I know, as the link suggests, but I want to know if there is a trick that will give me this. Something like NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()

Comment: getNetworkInterfaces() should return also interface with DOWN state. And also interfaces without IP addresses.

Comment: Strange, I just try it with windows. Maybe it works different way in Linux. There is isUp() function in the class. So it would even more stange if it does not ever return DOWN interfaces.

Comment: @User1 Yes, you're right, but if you have a network card that isn't configured yet, you won't see it in the Enumeration returned by getNetworkInterfaces() method. That's what I was talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig")` for Windows and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig")` for linux to get ifconfig result in java

There is no way to get to the gory details here in 100% Java. You can either execute commands or write JNI.

Comment: See the comment written for fsonmezay

Comment: @bmargulies Why would you edit someone's answer with an opinionated statement like that? Just leave a comment.

Comment: I added a fact to make the answer more complete after closing another question as a duplicate of this one. You could support your claim that my statement is mere opinion with another answer that offered contrary facts. If you did that, I'd upvote your answer and roll back my edit.