# How to get network card info with Java,if network card without IP configuration?

Tags: java, network-interface

I want to use **NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()** to list all interfaces, but I cannot list network card without IP configuration. 
And I can list all with **ifconfig** command.
so I want to know if there is a way to do this use Java.

For example,I cannot list this network card:

*ifconfig eth1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr -------------  

          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0

          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0

          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 

          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)*

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8613383/1553851

Comment: I have saw that question, so there is no way to do this with pure java. Thanks.