# Reading data from a file inside a zip file in java without extracting the Zip

Tags: java, java-io, filenotfoundexception, bufferedinputstream, zipinputstream

[image]

I need to read a file inside a zip folder without extracting Zip the zip folder then I need to keep all the data in that file in a buffer.

```
public static void getLogBuffers(String path) throws IOException
{
    String zipFileName = path;
    String destDirectory = path + "/..";

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFileName)));
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
    boolean isErrorLogFileExist = false;
    boolean isWindowLogFileExist = false;
    BufferedInputStream errorLogBuffer = null;
    BufferedInputStream windowLogBuffer = null;
    while (zipEntry != null)
    {
      String filePath = zipFileName + "/" + zipEntry.getName();
      System.out.println("unzipping" + filePath);
      if (!zipEntry.isDirectory())
      {
        //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith("errorlog.txt"))
        {
          isErrorLogFileExist = true;
          errorLogBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
          for (int i = errorLogBuffer.read(); i != -1; i = errorLogBuffer.read())
          {
            errorLogBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
          }
        }
```

`FileNotFoundException` is thrown in line

```java
errorLogBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

---

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\issues\log.zip\log\errorlog.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at errorWindowLogMapper.unZipFile(errorWindowLogMapper.java:113)
at errorWindowLogMapper.main(errorWindowLogMapper.java:38)
```

appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: @Abra cdslog.txt is there but the system can't detect it

Comment: You should be using a `ZipInputStream` to read

Comment: Use a **zip file system** (standard java) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538512/salvage-temporary-zip-file-with-java-filesystem It will allow you to use `Files.copy` to copy files into and out of the zip. Or rename or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File(zipPath));
        List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        ZipEntry entry = null;
        StringBuilder out = null;
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) 
       {
            entry = entries.nextElement();
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
                     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                            out.append(line);
                        }
       }
       return out.toString();
```