# Restart a computer running ubuntu using java without sudo rights?

Tags: java, restart

Is there any way i can restart my computer running Ubuntu 13.04 using a Java application without needing any sudo rights?

Comment: Is there a way to restart the computer at all without super user rights?

Comment: I am not sure,most probably no, thats why i asked the question here so that if there is any way

Comment: Of course not, that would be the world's biggest denial-of-service security hole in history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You need root privileges to run shutdown/reboot.

However, you can exec a system command which has setuid root and runs shudown/reboot.  Do you consider setuid/setgid equivalent to sudo for your question?  Not recommended.

Here is how to run a system command, ([How to execute system commands (linux/bsd) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java)).

Oh, and there is JNI (http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0510/Silverman/index.html), again setuid.

Another way to shutdown the system would be to connect to a Tcpip controlled power switch.  Then you could power off the system.  Did you ensure security on your ehternet power switch?  Powering the system back on is another challenge.