# Run sqoop commands through Java

Tags: hadoop

I am able to import data from sql server to hive using sqoop in command prompt as below:

```
>sqoop import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://localhost --username pavan -P --table my_Practice --hive-table my_Table --create-hive-table --hive-import -m 1
```

But i need to do the same using Java.
Can anyone suggest me how to import the data using sqoop in Java??

Comment: Are you looking for a way to [execute system commands using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java) ?

Comment: No not the system commands.@VusP

Comment: You can [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21012058/edit) the question and add your code to it.

Comment: I used the below code:     
  com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions options = new com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions();
  
  options.setConnectString("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost");
  options.setUsername("Pavan");
  options.setPassword("*******");
  options.setTableName("testtable");
  options.setNumMappers(1);
  options.setHiveTableName("testdata");
  options.setHiveImport(true);
  options.setOverwriteHiveTable(true);
           
  int ret = new ImportTool().run(options);

Comment: ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'testtable'.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'testtable'

ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Attempted to generate class with no columns!