# How to list the services I am authorized to start or stop in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, unix, service, linux-kernel

Please Help me out to resolve following Problem

```
chkconfig --list
```

I am using above command in linux to list all services.

It is listing all services running on that machine.

For some services, It wouldn't have privilege to start/stop.

Hence.. Kindly suggest me some way to get the services I am authorized to start/stop only..

Please help me out to list the services which I am authorized to start/stop...

Thanks.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com please post it there. Stack Overflow is for programming related questions.

Comment: Same that you want but for "uname -a" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/792049/797462).

Comment: I didn't get your solution @nigi . Here I will get all services running by using that command.. But I want only those service for which I am authorized to start/stop.........

Comment: With [NIO 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) you can check file permissions. google for 'java nio 2 check file permissions'