# Java code for curl request

Tags: java, curl, httpclient

I'm desperate to find answer myself so I need external help.

Need a java code, which done exactly this:
**curl --data "username=&password=&submit=Login" -v**

This is POST request to URL with data, which returns HEADERs, both sent and received.

Please advise! Thanks in advance!

Comment: java.lang.Runtime.exec("curl .....")?   See e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java

Comment: Do you mean you want to do the same in java. Or you really want java to run curl?

Comment: Are you actually wanting to use curl from java or are you just wanting to know how to accomplish equivalent functionality within java?

Comment: Did you try googling even once? I just googled "java curl example" and the first few links were stackoverflow question about this same topic.

Comment: In long term, yes! I need Java equivalent code. But now running from console is enough. Thanks to all of you for your interest to problem!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( //
    new String[] { //
    //
      "curl", //
      "--data", //
      "username=&password=&submit=Login" //
});
```

This below will call the `curl` tool and passing it the following parameters: `username=&password=&submit=Login`.

Comment: Should it print to console or I have to add this code? I'm sorry for dumb question, but I'm no Java developer but have to quickly fix Java application...

Comment: I've made it with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program

Comment: You can ask curl to log its actions or you can redirect the curl output in a file...