# how to apply css style in pdf using libreoffice

Tags: java, css, libreoffice

While I am converting `.html` to `.pdf` using LibreOffice in java. It is removing css style from the html file. it is considering inline css rather than css class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47721836/5100564

Comment: Thanks for advice but answer is using WKHTML but i am using LibreOffice for conversion in my case WKHTML is working fine if have idea of Libreoffice then plz share.

Comment: To this date, libreoffice (version 7.5.1.2 fcbaee479e84c6cd81291587d2ee68cba099e129) goes on ignoring styles when converting from html to pdf, even in command line.