# How two find unique difference between to files in Java and print their line numbers?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to text files and I want to print the line numbers where the contents of the second file is modified?

```
file 1:
1/ hi
2/ 
3/ 
4/ start
5/ {
6/ 
7/ while(){
8/ }
9/ }

file 2:
1/ hi
2/ 
3/ 
4/ 
5/ start
6/
7/
8/ {
9/ if(
10/ while(){
11/ }
12/ }.
```

The output should be: 9 (as an extra if is added in the file 2). Note, there might be unnecessary tabs and newlines.Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;



    //convert a file into a file_simple form
    File simplified(String src , String srcPath , String name) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File fileSrc = new File(src);
        File fileDest = new File(srcPath + "\\" + name + "_simple");
        Scanner scSrc = new Scanner(fileSrc);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileDest);
        while(scSrc.hasNextLine()) {
            String take = scSrc.nextLine();
            if(take.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            String take1 = take.trim();
            pw.println(take1);
        }
        pw.close();
        scSrc.close();
        return fileDest;
    }

     //write what difference the second file has
    void differenceInTwoFiles(File file1 , File file2 , String logPath , String UserName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file1Simple = simplified(file1.getAbsolutePath() , file1.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() , file1.getName());
        File file2Simple = simplified(file2.getAbsolutePath() , file2.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() , file2.getName());
        System.out.println(file2.getAbsolutePath() +" " + file2.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() +" "+ file2.getName());
        File log = new File(logPath); 
        PrintWriter pwLog = new PrintWriter(log);

        Scanner scF1 = new Scanner(file1Simple);
        Scanner scF2 = new Scanner(file2Simple);

        while(scF1.hasNextLine() && scF2.hasNextLine()) {
            String first = scF1.nextLine();
            String second = scF2.nextLine();
            if(!first.equals(second)) {
                pwLog.println(UserName + " has MODIFIED in " + file2.getName() + " : " + second);
            }
        }
        pwLog.close();
        scF1.close();
        scF2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for *not* using Java to handle this task, because there are already very good tools out there for doing along the lines of what you want.  For example, Linux has a `diff` tool which might work well here:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

At the very least, the output from `diff` would flag every line which were in disagreement between the two files, and maybe just that would be enough to meet your requirements.

Comment: but can i solve it in java? this is partial problem of my java project so..

Comment: You should have mentioned that this was homework, or at least that you needed to use Java.  In this case, you can just iterate both files and then flag lines which don't agree.  Any tutorial can get you started on how to do this.

Comment: @AyonRoyShouhag [Just use a system call to the linux os using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java) I think this would work